# Is there a way in SQL you can execute given formula in string format with parameters provided outside?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Like this:

```
DECLARE @FormulaString VARCHAR(100) == 'A * (B ^ C)'
EXEC spExecuteFormula @FormulaString, param1, param2, param3
```

?

Formulas are basic math formulas. Updated the formula above with a simple example which can't be executed via Sql Select.

Comment: Depending on the specifics of your formula you could probably write a CLR function in C# or similar. It would help if you could update your question so that it is specific about what formulas you need to handle.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the [Wolfram|Alpha API](https://www.wolframalpha.com/). It accepts vague requests and tries to provide justifiable answers, e.g. [1 gram in MW hours](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+gram+in+MW+hours).

Comment: Agreed on CLR, I was considering writing one, utilising one of the existing frameworks doing this but wanted to see if there is anything native in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can express it as a `SELECT` statement that takes parameters and use `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @FormulaString NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT @a + @b';

EXEC sp_executesql @FormulaString, 
                   N'@a int, @b int',
                   @a=3, @b=6;
```

Comment: I am talking about math formulas not sql statements. I know some can be done in this way but imagine you have these math formulas created by users and dynamically executed by the system. They contain symbols/operators which can't be part of a sql select.

Comment: What language is the formula specified in?

Comment: @Otake what formulas can't be handled in this manner? SQL has most normal operators.

Comment: @Otake . . . Use `power()` instead of `^`.  That is the function that (presumably) does what you want.  You cannot expect any software to have a general purpose parser for a language that *you* define.  You need to use the capabilities of the language.

Comment: These are user defined formulas so I can't expect them to write SQL nor update the existing ones. Not a language I define. As I said, basic math symbols so they are universal. Agreed, perhaps I can transform the formulas so they can be executed as "select" which I am considering or going with @DaleK's suggestion using CLR as there are .net frameworks doing this already.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your values types you could do something as simple as:

```
DECLARE @a INT = 1, @b INT = 1;

DECLARE @FormulaString NVARCHAR(100) = FORMATMESSAGE ('SELECT %i + %i AS Result;', @a, @b );
EXEC ( @FormulaString );
```

Returns

```
+--------+
| Result |
+--------+
|      2 |
+--------+
```